# I dislike Front-End but a lot of Junior Positions are FE only. Can I take such a role with a view to moving in to Back-End /Full-Stack later?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, developer

I'm a Junior Dev with 4 months professional Full-Stack experience. I'm leaving my current job soon for a better fit, but don't have the technical background necessary for many positions I'd like.

I'd be happy to only ever work in Back-End and DB as I like solving problems and the logical side of programming. I find working on the Front-End a whole different game, and one that I actively dislike, but I could tolerate it for a year if I thought it would help me to get where I want to go.
It seems a bad idea to discount all Front-End only positions, as they are probably my best chance of getting another job soon.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Do departments generally offer the chance to 'move around' to different areas if you're hired for something specific?
2. Will Front-End experience help me to get Full-Stack/Back-End positions in the future?

I would make the best of any position I did get, I'd just like to know whether I'd be shooting myself in the foot by getting more FE experience.

Comment: Thanks for replying Joe. I should clarify I'm leaving this position because of lack of support and poor technical practises. I could find one that's a good fit in those regards, but not what I want to be doing for long technology-wise.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered in general. The needs of any position are going to be as varied as the employers offering them. But, for what it's worth, I've managed to build my whole career sticking mostly to backend and database work. Front-end is a major blind spot for me, yet I remain happily employed. I'd be a terrible hire if an employer needed a front-end person though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to start developing yourself in the direction you want to go.

What does that mean? It means you have to start working on backend technologies on your own. Spin up a side project where you use postgress to host an API. Make another side project where you use a message queue of some kind. Read the google SRE book (which is free on line) and learn about systems at scale. You're a junior dev, as a whole you won't have the technical skills for a lot of things, that's ok, as long as you display the necessary passion and drive. With a couple of those on your belt, go out and apply to *any* position that seems to match your interests.

I'll go on to call out a mistake you are probably making. You're looking at job postings and seeing "we want a minimum of 2 years experience" and thinking that that is a hard cutoff. Its not. Job postings are wishlists. If you see a job you want, even if you're not qualified, you should *absolutely* apply. My first job wanted three years experience and a whole slew of technologies i'd never heard of. Turns out the person making the post got the hiring managers wishlist and just posted that.

To answer your actual questions

1. Depends entirely on the company, and its something to call out during the interview. I suspect though most companies billing for a FE engineer, want that, not a full stack engineer.
2. Yes for full stack, maybe for backend. The thing is your next job after your front end position will go off a lot of keywords in your resume, so it will depend on how you spin things. Really though, its realtively easy to call your FE position "Software Developer" without putting a specialization on it, and then just listing the accomplishments that fit the roles you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first point: It depends on which kind of company you'd like to apply to.

I was recently hired as a frontend/mobile developer in the startup I work with. When I arrived on my first day, they told me they needed me to work on the application's backend. Six months later I was asked if I could go back to working on the frontend. I'm now working as a full stack developer. What I'm trying to say is that from my experience (Western Europe), it's common and often required to switch from front to back end if you're working in a startup or as a consultant. Prior to my current job I was a consultant in a big international corporation and during the few years I spent there I worked on projects that involved various technologies from deep learning to software-defined networks, I programmed in C++ as well as in VueJS. I don't think you'd have that flexibility in traditional non-consulting companies.

Regarding your second point: It depends. As long as you don't stick to frontend jobs for years I think you're safe, but you should definitely express to management your interest to go full stack/backend from the beginning. Technological watch or personal projects seem like a nice addition too, as they would show your determination to try something else.

A piece of advice for you: not because you don't have the experience yet does it mean you wouldn't be a great fit for a position. That's what job interviews are for, they provide the future employer with the possibility to evaluate whether you would learn quickly and do great work in a team. I didn't feel qualified for my current job (for which, again, I didn't sign, as I was supposed to do frontend programming) but they believed in me and I've learned so much since I first got here. Don't be afraid to try, and don't be afraid to try new things either (new technologies, new languages, ...) if that's what you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll be forward with what I want and see what opportunities come up. Sounds like interesting things come up!